# Can you explain in mathematical term of how the moon makes the earth spin stable?

Tags: astronomy, rotational-dynamics

I heard that our moon keeps the earth's rotation at the same angle. This is, as the Science Channel explained, is essential for regular seasons on earth. I am not interesting in the fact why it is vital for life. However, I would like to know the mathematical explanation to this phenomena.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I have found the following paper, which indicates that the case may not be as clear as some popular programs have suggested: "Our Large Moon Does Not Stabilize Earth’s Axis", D. Waltham, EPSC Abstracts Vol. 8, EPSC2013-37, 2013. Whether the paper is any good I can't say, but it does contain a citation of what seems to be regarded as the original paper on the topic: Laskar, J., Joutel, F., and Robutel, P.: Stabilization of the Earth’s obliquity by the Moon, Nature, Vol. 361, pp. 615-617, 1993

Comment: Thank. I really appreciate it. It just a bit like story telling when I tell my students about this fact/theory and I can't prove it to them.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I always had a feeling that this story wasn't quite as straight forward as it appeared and now we know that the argument for the stabilizing effect is not totally trivial.